# display two date field value formated like "Monthname dd-dd, YYYY"

Tags: mysql, date-format

I have a mysql table with two date fields. Startdate and Enddate are the fields
I need to display the dates in the front end like "24-26 October, 2014" using the fields

How can i accomplish this?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be something like this

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(StartDate,'%M') + DATE_FORMAT(StartDate,'%d') + '-' + DATE_FORMAT(EndDate,'%d') + ',' + DATE_FORMAT(StartDate,'%Y') 
FROM YourTable
```

**[MySQL Date_Format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)**